# R - Is there a way to temporarily set context-specific plot parameters in R as done in python using "with" statement?

Tags: python, r, plot, size, with-statement

In Python, you can set context specific (i.e. temporarily change) plot parameters with a `with` statement as given below.
***Question 2 :*** Can the same be done in R?

**My current code:**

```
# save default parameters
defop = options()

# sunction to set plot parameters
plot_pars = function(w=7,h=7) {options(repr.plot.width=w, repr.plot.height=h)}

# set plot size
plot_pars(10,4)

# generate boxplot
boxplot(Outstate ~ Elite, data=college, horizontal=T, col=5:6,
       xlab="Elite", ylab="Outstate tuition (USD)")

# reset parameters
options(defop)
```

I have to reset the plot parameters every time I change them. There must be a way to avoid this.
[image]

***Question 2 :*** Is there a function/device with functionality similar to `with` in python?

***Python Code:***

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import requests

## import data
url = "https://statlearning.com/College.csv"  # ISLR repository
df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

```
## generate boxplot with specified dimensions
with plt.rc_context():
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3))
    sns.boxplot(y='Private', x='Outstate', data=df);
# boxplot generated with specified dimensions
```

[image]

```
## generate boxplot normally
sns.boxplot(y='Private', x='Outstate', data=df);
# boxplot generated with default dimensions
# defaults were not changed as the plt.figure() was
# within 'with' container
```

[image]

Comment: So what do you want your R code to look like? What settings do you want to temporarily change?

Comment: I want to increase the plot size to (10,3).

Comment: 10 and 3 what? Are you trying to control the size of the resulting image? In R, the size of the plot is not a property of the plot. Plots resize them selves to fit whatever graphics device you choose. So you set the height/width of the graphics device. This is a lot of python code for an R question. Why not take a step back and forget python exists, and talk specifically about what you are trying to accomplish in R with a proper R example.

Comment: @MrFlick, I have updated the question with the R code, I currently use. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** `with_par` in the [withr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=withr) package can temporarily set those classic graphics parameters settable in `par` within a scope and outside the scope are automatically set back.

**2)** You can alternately just reset the parameters back after finishing (no packages needed):

```
opar <- par(...whatever...)
# plotting commands
par(opar)
```

To use this within a function one possibility is to put the `par(opar)` in an `on.exit` to automatically reset the parameters on exit.

```
f <- function() {
  on.exit(par(opar))

  opar <- par(...whatever...)
  # plotting commands
}
```

Comment: I already use this way. But the parameters need to be reset every time in this option. I was looking for a way to avoid this repetitive resetting.

Comment: Would you mind posting a sample code on how to use with_par and options(repr.plot.width=10, repr.plot.height=4)?

Comment: ```with_par(options(repr.plot.width=10), plot(xx, yy))``` did not work.
```with_par(list=(options(repr.plot.width=10)), plot(xx, yy))```  also did not work.

Comment: So, how can I use ```with_par``` to temporarily change plot dimensions (having the same effect as ```options(repr.plot.width=10, repr.plot.height=3)```?
Please give an example code.

Comment: I tried ```library(withr)
with_options(list(repr.plot.width=10, repr.plot.height=4), plot(rnorm(1000)))``` Didn't work. I  also printed the in-built example with ```library(withr); example(with_options)```. It didn't have an example of changing plot parameters.

Comment: There are no options with those name in base R.  Maybe you are using some package which was omitted from the question?

Comment: Yes, apparantely 'repr' package that gives this option is installed with IRkernel package ('Native R kernel for the 'Jupyter Notebook').

Answer (score 1):

You can write a basic helper function for this. Here we write a generic wrapper function that will return a function that will evaluate your code with whatever options you like and then will reset them afterwards. We can make a special helper just for with width and height values.

```
with_options <- function(...) {
  function(code) {
    orig <- options()
    on.exit(options(orig))
    options(...)
    force(code)
  }
}
with_repr_size <- function(w=7, h=8) 
  with_options(repr.plot.width=w, repr.plot.height=h)
```

Then you can use it with something like

```
#sample data
set.seed(10)
college <- data.frame(
  Elite = runif(100) < .4,
  Outstate = rnorm(100,1200,200)
)

with_repr_size(w=10, h=4)({
  boxplot(Outstate ~ Elite, data=college, horizontal=T, col=5:6,
          xlab="Elite", ylab="Outstate tuition (USD)");
  print(options("repr.plot.height"))   # for testing
})
print(options("repr.plot.height"))     # for testing
```

This is similar to what functions like [withr::with_options](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/withr/versions/2.3.0/topics/with_options) would do if you would prefer to use code from a package rather than write your own.

Comment: This did not work for me. The figure that is generated is not 10x4.

Comment: Note: I'm using R in Jupyter notebook.